# Behavior of summing !is.na() results

Tags: r, logical-operators, na, operator-precedence

Why does the first line return TRUE, and the third line returns 1? I would expect both lines to return 1. What is the exact meaning of those extra two parentheses in the third line?

```
!is.na(5) + !is.na(NA)
# TRUE
(!is.na(5)) + (!is.na(NA))
# 1
```

edit: should check these multiple times. The original problem was with `!is.na()`, thought it replicated for `is.na()`. But it didn't :)

Comment: ... Didn't make sure... I the original issue was with !is.na(). Try it now :)

Comment: This also holds for `!TRUE + !FALSE` and `(!TRUE) + (!FALSE)`. I.e., it's nothing to do with `is.na`

Comment: @Xachriel Since you are relatively new here you might want to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and the [**faq**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) about how SO works. StackOverflow is made much more valuable to everyone if when you receive an answer that solves your problem (you have a great answer!!!), you accept it by clicking the little check mark or upvote a useful answer. You are under absolutely no obligation to do either, but it is a great way to "give back" to the site if an answer did in fact solve your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`!` has a weird, counter-intuitive precedence in R.](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Syntax.html)

Your first code is equivalent to

```
!(is.na(5) + !is.na(NA))
```

That is, `!` has lower precedence than `+`.

Comment: +1 - Which means you can get bizarre outcomes like: `!TRUE + FALSE equals FALSE` and `FALSE + !TRUE equals 0` This hurts my brain.

Comment: For Lispers: `codetools::showTree(quote(!is.na(5) + !is.na(NA)))`

Comment: Just goes to show:  regardless of the language in question, use a few extra sets of brackets to avoid ambiguities.

Comment: @Carl I consider that a very bad guideline. Redundant parentheses introduce visual clutter that needs to be weighed against the increased explicitness. For elementary operations (think BODMAS, but for programmers), redundant parentheses become detrimental to readability.

Comment: De gustibus non disputandam.  A decent editor will provide color or other highlighting to match braces.  I understand the readability problem, so I'm not suggesting massive bracket overkill.   One other point: code often ends up being ported from one language to another. Whenever there's a nonstandard or nonintuitive precedence, brackets help a lot.