# Does operator precedence explain the difference in these expressions involving multiplication of a numeric with a negated logical?

Tags: r, logical-operators, operator-precedence, not-operator

I have three expressions, each involving multiplication with a logical or its negation. These logicals and their negation represent indicator variables, so that the expressions are conditionally evaluated:

```
-2*3*!T + 5*7*T
5*7*T + -2*3*!T 
(-2*3*!T) + 5*7*T
```

I expect the above to produce the same result. However:

```
> -2*3*!T + 5*7*T
[1] 0          # unexpected!
> 5*7*T + -2*3*!T 
[1] 35
> (-2*3*!T) + 5*7*T
[1] 35
```

I am sure this has something to do with [operator precedence](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html) and type coercion, but I can't work out how it makes sense to even evaluate `!T` after the `*`.

Comment: Almost certainly an issue with `!` as `-2*3*(!T) + 5*7*T` works too.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like best practice would be to enclose the negations in brackets first in such expressions.

Comment: Also relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651687/behavior-of-summing-is-na-results Which suggests also looking at `codetools::showTree(quote( -2*3*(!T) + 5*7*T ))` vs. `codetools::showTree(quote( -2*3*!T + 5*7*T ))` if you're familiar with Lisp code.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what I was looking for, I just didn't know how to look for it.

Comment: The votes-to-close are wrong; this is a good and clear question. R's logical-not operator does indeed have a precedence bug, we all learn the hard way. When I hit it (in a compound expression), it cost me >10 hours of head-scratching.

Comment: @smci, thanks. Unfortunately sometimes it is just not possible to make anyone see reason, at any time ;)

Comment: @Alex, we try to put the 'R' into reason... or is that the other way around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're exactly right that this is about operator precedence. As `?base::Syntax` (which you link above) states, `!` has lower precedence than all of the arithmetic operators, so the first expression is equivalent to

```
(-2*3)*!(T + 5*7*T)
```

(because the expression containing `!` has to be evaluated before the final multiplication can be done) or

```
-6*!(36)  # T coerced to 1 in numeric operations
```

or

```
-6*FALSE  # non-zero numbers coerced to TRUE in logical operations
```

or

```
-6*0      # FALSE coerced to 0 in numeric operations
```

Comment: Thanks. I was really struggling to find the first expression you wrote down.